# How to draw BST with recursion in this format?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
void printGivenLevel(node *root, int level, int side, int x, int y)
{
  if(root == NULL)
   return;

   if(level == 1)
   {
     gotoxy(x, y);
     cout << root->data;
   }
   else if(level > 1)
   {
      if(y<=2)
      {
        printGivenLevel(root->left, level-1, 1, x-4, y);
        printGivenLevel(root->right,level-1, 2, x+4, y);
      }
      else
      {
        printGivenLevel(root->left, level-1, 1, x-2, y);
        printGivenLevel(root->right,level-1, 2, x+2, y);
      }
   }
}
void print(node *root)
 {
   int h = height(root);
   int i;
   int side = 0; // Use 1 for left and 2 for right 
   int x = 42; //42 is the center of console

   for(i=1;i<=h;i++)
   {
     printGivenLevel(root, i, side, x, i);
     cout << endl;
   }

  }
```

I am using c++ and need the BST like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6imof.png)
.The code above can only format up to level 1. I didn't include the underscore yet because I was trying to fix the spaces first. I'm looking for a way to format this without using anything too complicated like queues and I'm also using turbo c++ any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to provide all code necessary to compile the functions you pasted here. Also, maybe provide a `main` function that builds a tree and prints it. This way, people can start messing with your code right away instead of writing their own first. You are not guaranteed an answer but it will at least make people more inclined to help you.

Comment: Also note that the `print` function iteratively calls `printGivenLevel` while the function `printGivenLevel` also recursively calls itself. You need to choose either one but not both. If you want recursion (as stated in the question title), simply call `printGivenLevel` once in the `print` function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  @MaartenBamelis was quite correct; I'll be more direct: you posted partial code, no specifications, and no actual output; the missing parts make it unlikely that you'll get much help.

Comment: Sorry about that guys I'll try to provide more information next time. I was actually have more of a problem with logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you failed to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at the time of writing this answer, I just made my own.

From your question, I gather that your main issue is getting the recursion to work. The code I provide in this answer should give you insight on how to solve that issue.

There is still one shortcoming: every node of the tree is printed on a separate line.

---

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Node
{
    Node(Node* l, Node* r, std::string d) : left(l), right(r), data(d) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    std::string data;
};

void printTree(Node& root, int minx, int maxx)
{
    auto x = ((minx + maxx) / 2);

    auto o = ((x - minx) / 2);
    auto w = std::string(x - o, ' ');
    auto u = std::string(o, '_');
    std::cout << w << u << root.data << u << std::endl;

    if (root.left != nullptr)
        printTree(*(root.left), minx, x);

    if (root.right != nullptr)
        printTree(*(root.right), x, maxx);  
}

int main()
{
    auto lrll = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "1" };
    auto lrlr = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "2" };
    auto lll = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "3" };
    auto llr = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "4" };
    auto lrl = new Node{ lrll, lrlr, "5" };
    auto lrr = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "6" };
    auto ll = new Node{ lll, llr, "7" };
    auto lr = new Node{ lrl, lrr, "8" };
    auto rl = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "9" };
    auto rr = new Node{ nullptr, nullptr, "10" };
    auto l = new Node{ ll, lr, "11" };
    auto r = new Node{ rl, rr, "12" };

    auto root = std::make_unique<Node>(l, r, "13");
    printTree(*root, 0, 84);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
                     _____________________13_____________________
           __________11__________
     _____7_____
   __3__
             __4__
                          _____8_____
                        __5__
                      _1_
                           _2_
                                  __6__
                                                     __________12__________
                                               _____9_____
                                                                    _____10_____
```

---

**Note:** not all underscores line up perfectly because `84` is chosen as the initial max value (I did this to get the root at position `42`).

Any binary tree can be perfectly represented in the most compact way by correctly choosing the initial min and max value according to the following formula:

`max - min == 2^(h)` with h == the height of the tree

For the tree (of height 5) used in my code, the perfect representation requires:

`max - min == 2^(5) == 32`

As such, calling `printTree()` with any min and max value that differ by 32, will yield a perfect and most compact representation of the tree. For example, calling it as follows

`printTree(*root, 0, 32)`

results in the following output:

```
        ________13________
    ____11____
  __7__
 _3_
     _4_
          __8__
         _5_
         1
           2
             _6_
                    ____12____
                  __9__
                          __10__
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.